# convert mysql_fetch_row result into javascript array

Tags: php, javascript

i m trying to convert php mysql_fetch_row result into javascript array so i write below code to do that. but i got problem , if there are multiple row in result, then only last row stored in javascript array

```
<script>
function sub()
{
alert("coming");
var a= new Array;
<?php
$dbhost ='localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'pupilcafe';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die ('Error Connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn);
$uid=1;
$semester='1stSemester';    
$cid=1;
$qry="select * from subject where cid='$cid'&& uid='$uid'&& semester='$semester'";
$res = mysql_query($qry);
while($data=mysql_fetch_row($res))
{
$i=0;
echo "a[$i]='".$data[1]."';";
$i++;
}
?>
alert(a[0]);
}
</script>
```

so here mysql code fetch two row frm db (Englishphp) but in result i got only php .. i want both of this row in javascript array
so how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't concoct Javascript syntax yourself. Use `json_encode`:

```
$a = array();
while ($data = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
    $a[] = $data[1];
}

?>

<script>
    var a = <?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;
</script>
```

Also, mysql_ functions are deprecated. Don't use them for new code. Use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should follow some guidelines on coding. Your way of coding is not neat.
Stop using mysql_query. It is getting depreciated and start using PDO. Search in google about that.
Second, you should escape your variables that you are using in your query to avoid sql injection. What you want cannot be achieved with the code you have written.

```
function sub() {

    //your queries and other stuff here

    while($data=mysql_fetch_row($res))
    {

        $tempArray[] = $data;

    }

    return json_encode($tempArray);
}
?>

<script language = "javascript">

    window.addEventListener("onload", function () {
        var temArray = "<?php echo sub(); ?>";

        alert(tempArray);

    }, false);

</script>
```

The onload eventListener will tell if the page is loaded. Without that it mightbe possible that your function call sub() might give you an error "undefined function" because its not yet loaded.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek.! ya i will search about pdo also